# I want to check the value of subquery how to check it?

Tags: mysql, subquery

This is my update query in mysql

```
UPDATE userentries
SET User_Rank = 
(
  SELECT 
  urc.rankofentr as User_Rank
  from UserRankingsys as urc 
  WHERE urc.entryid = userentries.id
  LIMIT 1
) 
where userentries.id = 15
```

I want to check the value which is returned by that section

```
(
  SELECT 
  urc.rankofentr as User_Rank
  from UserRankingsys as urc 
  WHERE urc.entryid = userentries.id
  LIMIT 1
)
```

how i can do this if this sub query returns greater than 20 than i want to set the value 102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE

```
  SELECT case urc.rankofentr when > 20 then 20 
                             else urc.rankofentr
         end as User_Rank
  from UserRankingsys as urc 
  WHERE urc.entryid = userentries.id
  LIMIT 1
```

for you sql

```
UPDATE userentries
SET User_Rank = 
(
 SELECT case urc.rankofentr when > 20 then 20 
                             else urc.rankofentr
         end as User_Rank
  from UserRankingsys as urc 
  WHERE urc.entryid = userentries.id
  LIMIT 1
) 
where userentries.id = 15;
```

Comment: but i am getting value from sub query how i apply case on subquery value ?